# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException raised even though @Autowire and @ repository @ service are properly configured

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, struts2

My controller class:

```
@Controller
public class UsersController
{
    @Autowired
    TechRequestService techrequestservices;

@RequestMapping(value="/service_request", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody  Map<String,Object> SaveServiceRequest(@Valid Servicerequest servicerequest,BindingResult result){
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        Object obj=new Object();
            if(result.hasErrors())
            {  
                for (Object object : result.getAllErrors()) {
                    if(object instanceof FieldError) {
                        FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

                     obj= (fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
                    }
                map.put("status","400");
                map.put("message",obj);
                return map;
            }}
            techrequestservices.save_servicerequest(servicerequest);
            map.put("status","200");
            map.put("message","Your record have been saved successfully"); 
            return map;
            }

}
```

My Service Implementation class:

```
@Service

    public class TechRequestServiceImpl implements TechRequestService{
        @Autowired
        TechRequestServiceDao techrequestservicedao;

        public boolean save_servicerequest(Servicerequest servicerequest) {
            return techrequestservicedao.save_servicerequest(servicerequest);
        }

        public List<Servicerequest> list() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return techrequestservicedao.list();
        }



    }
```

My DaoImpl Class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class TechRequestServiceDaoImpl implements TechRequestService {

    @Autowired
SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public boolean save_servicerequest(Servicerequest servicerequest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(servicerequest);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Servicerequest> list() {

            return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Search_type_case").list();

    }
}
```

> The request comes through ajax and the pojo variables are getting their values initialized properly as i confirmed it by placing a print statement in ever setter method of pojos. The full stack trace of the exception as follows:
>
> ```
> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
> ```
>
> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'usersController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.servicesapi.TechRequestService
>   com.controllers.UsersController.techrequestservices; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'techRequestServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.daoapi.TechRequestServiceDao
>   com.servicesimpl.TechRequestServiceImpl.techrequestservicedao; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.daoapi.TechRequestServiceDao] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `TechRequestServiceImpl` and `TechRequestServiceDaoImpl` implements `TechRequestService` therefore there are two beans of type `TechRequestService` in the context, but none of type: `TechRequestServiceDao`.
To fix: `TechRequestServiceDaoImpl` should implement `TechRequestServiceDao`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude it was spot on!! works perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

Is your `Component-Scan` set correctly to scan packages inside a given path? Try setting the `component-scan` in the `spring xml configuration` to scan the relevant packages as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.main"/>
```

where your `dao`, `service` and `controller` packages are located inside `com.main`. This will scan all files under `com.main` while checking for bean definations.

Comment: I have used: <context:component-scan base-package="com" /> so it will scan all packages with name com